# Dell Inspiron 530 poor network speeds with file copy

Tags: networking, dell-inspiron

For some reason file copies are taking too long to/from my Dell Inspiron 530. It is possible that the performance deteriorated after upgrading to Windows 7.

Comment: Probably more appropriate for Superuser.

Answer (score 0):

Under the properties of the network adapter on the Advanced tab change the value of "Wait for Link" from "Auto Detect" to "Off." This completely solved the issue for me.